# Average of values in the same column based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate the average of some numbers in the same column every 5 minutes.
These data can come every 30 seconds or 1 minute.
I would like the time to be used as a reference to calculate this average.

I tried the method below, but I had to include the time later and it only works if it's 1 minute; I couldn't calculate the average considering the time.

```
Planilha = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data/hora': ['01/02/2024 05:01','01/02/2024 05:02','01/02/2024 05:03','01/02/2024 05:04','01/02/2024 05:05','01/02/2024 05:06','01/02/2024 05:07','01/02/2024 05:08','01/02/2024 05:09','01/02/2024 05:10','01/02/2024 05:11','01/02/2024 05:12','01/02/2024 05:13','01/02/2024 05:14','01/02/2024 05:15'],
    'Valores_ok' : [21.48544006,32.41119499,44.18326492,59.37920151,76.55416718,93.16954193,121.0470154,164.0023529,207.9371277,198.1840485,150.4580994,144.5747345,155.5020691,155.5775085,160.8874695],
})

Irrad = Planilha.iloc[:,Planilha.columns.str.contains('Valores')] #Filtering the necessary data

IrradM = pd.DataFrame()
IrradM.columns = pd.DataFrame(columns=Irrad.columns)

for i in range(0, len(Irrad), 5):
    Irrad5m = Irrad.iloc[i:i+5].mean(numeric_only=True)
    Irrad5m = pd.DataFrame(Irrad5m).T
    IrradM = pd.concat([IrradM, Irrad5m], ignore_index=True)
```

Another issue is the delay due to the amount of data.
I imagine there must be a much easier way to perform this operation.

Input data

```
       Data/hora  Valores_ok
01/02/2024 05:01   21.485440
01/02/2024 05:02   32.411195
01/02/2024 05:03   44.183265
01/02/2024 05:04   59.379202
01/02/2024 05:05   76.554167
01/02/2024 05:06   93.169542
01/02/2024 05:07  121.047015
01/02/2024 05:08  164.002353
01/02/2024 05:09  207.937128
01/02/2024 05:10  198.184048
01/02/2024 05:11  150.458099
01/02/2024 05:12  144.574735
01/02/2024 05:13  155.502069
01/02/2024 05:14  155.577508
01/02/2024 05:15  160.887470
```

Expected output

```
       Data/hora  Valores_ok
01/02/2024 05:05   46.802654
01/02/2024 05:10  156.868017
01/02/2024 05:15  153.399976
```

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: User guide: [Time series / date functionality § Resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows how you can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to average together at 5-minute intervals. I've also included a comparison with a [rolling-window](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html) average, which gives you a 5-minute average at each row. There is some plotting at the end to view the results.

The code starts by preprocessing the dataframe:

- Load the data, converting commas to a decimal point
- Convert the date column to a `pandas`-compatible date-time format
- I prefer to set the date column as the index

Finally, it resamples using `.resample('5min')`. I configure it to match your averages.

[image]

---

Load and prepare the data:

```py
import pandas as pd

#Load data
df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', decimal=',')
df = df[['Data /Hora', 'Valores ']]

#Rename columns
df = df.rename(columns={'Data /Hora': 'data', 'Valores ': 'valores'})

#Convert column to DateTime format
# I am assuming the format is: day/month/year 12-hour format:minute
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%d/%m/%y %I:%M')

#Set date as index
df = df.set_index('data')
```

Resample to 5-minute boundaries:

```py
#Create resampled column
df['valores_resampled_5min'] = df['valores'].resample('5min', label='right', closed='right').mean()

#Optional
# Using a rolling window is a different way of averaging values.
# It will look back 5min at each row, and average the values
df['valores_rolling_5min'] = df['valores'].rolling('5min').mean()
```

View the results:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3))

ax.plot(df.index, df['valores'], marker='o', linewidth=2, color='lightgray', label='valores')
ax.scatter(df.index, df['valores_resampled_5min'], marker='s', color='crimson', label='resampled 5min')
ax.step(df.index, df['valores_resampled_5min'].bfill(), linestyle=':', linewidth=1.1, color='crimson')
ax.plot(df.index, df['valores_rolling_5min'], linewidth=3, color='tab:purple', label='rolling 5min', zorder=0)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator=None))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())
ax.grid(axis='x', which='both', linestyle=':', color='gainsboro')
ax.set(xlabel='time', ylabel='valores')
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(50, 200)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(mdates.date2num(df.index[0]), mdates.date2num(df.index[-1]))
f.legend()
```

Comment: Beside the point, but why did you call the dataframe `csv`? It's not a CSV anymore once it's loaded and that could be confused with the stdlib module `csv`. Why not just call it `df`?

Comment: You don't actually need to set the datetime as the index, you can just use the `on` parameter to `.resample()` (and `.rolling()`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have amended my answer. The `on=` is good to know. I set the index out of preference, which I've now clarified in the answer.